# Postgres 'group' parent by number of children

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of Stores (Parent) and Products (Child). I wish to know how many stores have:

- 0-1 products
- 2 products
- 3 products
- 4 products
- 5 or more products.

Can anyone point me in the right direction

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What's table structure?

Comment: `SELECT stores, count(child) as noofchilds FROM tablename GROUP BY stores ORDER BY 1, 2;` - this should return the list of stores with count of products.

Comment: Count the number of products per store in a Derived Table, then group by this count

Comment: Thanks @MaciejLos I got I working :) Could you post and answer

Comment: @TommySadiqHinrichsen, You're very welcome. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the list of stores with count of products.

```
SELECT stores, count(child) as noofchilds
FROM tablename
GROUP BY stores
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

To get count of stores, you'll need to group stores like this:

```
SELECT noofchilds as childscount, count(stores) as noofstores
FROM
(
    -- use above query without ORDER BY clause
) t
GROUP BY t.noofchilds
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want `0`, then you need a `left join` -- and aggregation.  You can put the information into separate rows for each counting using two levels of aggregation:

```
select num_products, count(*)
from (select s.store_id, count(p.store_id) as num_products
      from stores s left join
           products p
           on p.store_id = p.store_id
      group by s.store_id
     ) s
group by num_products
order by num_products;
```

If you want ranges, then conditional aggregation in the outer query may be simpler:

```
select count(*) filter (where num_products <= 1),
       count(*) filter (where num_products = 2),
       count(*) filter (where num_products = 3),
       count(*) filter (where num_products = 4),
       count(*) filter (where num_products >= 5)           
from (select s.store_id, count(p.store_id) as num_products
      from stores s left join
           products p
           on p.store_id = p.store_id
      group by s.store_id
     ) s
group by num_products
order by num_products;
```